# Primefaces adds .xhtml extention to css and .js files when rendered so styles and JavaScript don't work

Tags: css, web-applications, jsf-2, primefaces

I try to create a webApp using Primefaces 4.0 and spring 3.2.5 for Dependency injection.

Primefaces dependencies:

```
    <!-- primefaces and jsf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${primafaces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>blitzer</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
        <artifactId>home</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

This is the login page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="mainPageHelper.js" />

    <h:outputStylesheet name="login-page.css" library="css" />
</h:head>

<h:body onload="checkErrorStatus();">

<h:form id="f" styleClass="f" name="f" method="POST">

    <h:outputText styleClass="error" style="color:red; display:none; background-color:     #C2DFFF">given username and/or password incorrect</h:outputText>

    <h:outputText>Log in</h:outputText>

    <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="3" cellpadding="4">

        <p:outputLabel value="Username:" />
        <p:inputText id="username" name="j_username" required="true" requiredMessage="Username is required" size="25" style="width:120px;" />
        <p:message for="username"/>

        <h:outputLabel value="Password:" />
        <h:inputSecret id="password" name="j_password" required="true" requiredMessage="Password is required" style="width:120px;" size="25" />
        <p:message for="password"/>

        <p:commandButton id="loginRedirect" value="Login" action="#{loginController.loginRedirect}" ajax="false" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>

</h:body>

</html>
```

As you can see, I am trying to import my own styling and my own Javascript. The resources are found, but when the page is created, an **.xhtml** extension is added to each file, even to the primefaces javascript and css, as seen below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/ePIBWebApp/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces-home">
     <link type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" href="/ePIBWebApp/javax.faces.resource/login- page.css.xhtml?ln=css">
     <link   type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/ePIBWebApp/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0">
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/ePIBWebApp/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml?
ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
     <style type="text/css"></style>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/ePIBWebApp/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&amp;v=4.0"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="/ePIBWebApp/javax.faces.resource/mainPageHelper.js.xhtml?ln=js"></script>
</head>
 <body onload="checkErrorStatus();">
 <form id="f" name="f" method="post" action="/ePIBWebApp/pages/login.xhtml" class="f"   enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
 <input type="hidden" name="f" value="f">
 <span class="error" style="color:red; display:none; background-color: #C2DFFF"></span><table  id="f:grid" cellpadding="4">
 <tbody>
<tr>
<td><label id="f:j_idt12" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget">Username:</label></td>
<td><input id="f:username" name="f:username" type="text" size="25" style="width:120px;"  class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><script id="f:username_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('InputText','widget_f_username',{id:'f:username'});</script>   </td>
 <td><div id="f:j_idt13" aria-live="polite" class="ui-message"></div></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td><label>
Password:</label></td>
 <td><input id="f:password" type="password" name="f:password" value="" size="25"      style="width:120px;"></td>
 <td><div id="f:j_idt15" aria-live="polite" class="ui-message"></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td><button id="f:loginRedirect" name="f:loginRedirect" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-  default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" type="submit">
 <span class="ui-button-text ui-c">Login</span></button><script id="f:loginRedirect_s"  type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw('CommandButton','widget_f_loginRedirect', {id:'f:loginRedirect'});</script></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
 </table>
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState"  value="4305835440482722754:-5118499173786020406" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

The web.xml is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<display-name>Hello world web application using PrimeFaces and Spring</display-name>

<!-- Spring Context Configuration' s Path definitions -->
<context-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
      </param-value>
 </context-param>

  <!-- The Bootstrap listener to start up and shut down Spring's root WebApplicationContext. 
        It is registered to Servlet Container -->

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Project Stage Level -->
    <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security tag library for JSF -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

     <!-- Welcome Page -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
     </welcome-file-list>

     <!-- Spring Security filter Chain -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <!-- Filter Mappings -->
     <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
         <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
         <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
         <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
     </filter-mapping>

    <!-- JSF Servlet is defined to container -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

     <!-- Mapping with servlet and url for the http requests. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
         <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>log4jConfig.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableMissingResourceLibraryDetection</param-name>
         <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
         <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>home</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- 
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>css</extension>
        <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>js</extension>
        <mime-type>text/javascript</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>txt</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>gif</extension>
        <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpeg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>jpg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xml</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

security works.. I can log in with the credentials. I don't know what I did wrong in the configuration or why the .xhtml extension is added.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: PrimeFaces doesn't do that. It's standard JSF. Your Spring Security configuration is just invalid. You incorrectly (implicitly) told it to also block access to CSS/JS/image resources coming from `/javax.faces.resource/*`. An easy test is to disable/remove Spring Security. You'll see that CSS/JS/image resources start to "work" (i.e. they will return normal HTTP 200 response instead of a login page ... check HTTP traffic monitor).

Comment: Thanks a lot! indeed adding a `<intercept-url pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" access="permitAll" />` solved the problem. CSS and the Javascript files are now retrieved.